# Exact Permissions\actions needed to List Azure Resources using C# rest API

Tags: c#, user-permissions, rbac, azure-rest-api

I am trying to list all resources in a Subscription using Rest API Call.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resources?api-version=2021-04-01
```

It works fine when I run it with **Built-In** RBAC Role ***Reader*** Permissions. For security reasons, I wanted to avoid having read access to entire scope of subscription. So, I need to create a ***Custom Role*** with specific ***permissions\actions*** to list all Resources in a Subscription.

I am trying with below Custom Role but not able to get any response from Rest API call.

```
{
"properties": {
    "roleName": "AzResourceTest",
    "description": "To test the exact ACLs needed to get Resources List from a Subscription",
    "assignableScopes": [
        "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "actions": [
                "Microsoft.Resources/resources/read"
            ],
            "notActions": [],
            "dataActions": [],
            "notDataActions": []
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Can someone please suggest what should I use in ***actions*** to get resources.

Comment: Got it. "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resources/read" is the action for Custom Role to list resources in a subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. "***Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resources/read***" is the action for Custom Role to list resources in a subscription